# Understanding how http requests work on Mocha

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, mocha.js, chai

I understand that mocha uses superagent under the hood, but how does it work when I haven't started a local server? Does mocha start a server by itself and send http requests to it or am I misunderstanding how mocha works in the first place?

For clarity, I checked and currently I do not have a local server running and that's when I got a bit confused as to how mocha tests work under the hood

Answer (score 2):

Mocha runs JavaScript code with Node, just like your npm scripts which runs your local server. You just don't see it on the console like you do when you enter `npm run debug` or whatever your script is. So under the hood it's just Node running the JavaScript.

Which is why you don't need to start a server because it's already running while tests are executing. You just aren't seeing the console logs you're use to, except for what Mocha prints of course. See their [page](https://mochajs.org/#getting-started) for more details.